# Local Forage and Angular - issue with Get Item from Local Storage

Tags: angularjs, localforage

I have an `angular model` named rows.

I have a piece of code that tries to fetch data from local storage using `LocalForage` and set the local data to the rows model.

Apparently, it seems like, by the time the local storage call back for get item executes, the `$scope.rows` model goes out of scope.

Is there a way, i can achieve this, that is set the value from local storage to the rows model?

```
    localforage.getItem(localBlogKey, function (err, readValue) 
    {
     if (readValue !== null && readValue !== undefined) 
         {
           var localdata = readValue.data;                    
           $scope.rows = angular.fromJson(localData);
         }
     });
```

Since this piece of code runs asynchronously, the `$scope.rows` goes out of scope? Is there a sunchronous way to pull data from localforage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved using the ngStorage Module.
 Import the ngStorage module and then access the localstorage item with the key as below

```
  localstorage.myKey = "myValue";
```

This is Synchronous and hence my issue is resolved.